# For statement missing out the last object every time

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop

I am using the following code to try and put objects in an array. I need a specific number of objects in that array - the count of another array (which is 36).

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[self.titlearray objectForKey:@"Title"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[self.titlearray setObject:sortedKeys forKey:@"Title"];

NSLog(@"SORTED KEYS COUNT: %i", sortedKeys.count);

for (NSObject *string in sortedKeys) {

    NSLog(@"Adding object number %i", [sortedKeys indexOfObject:string]);

    NSString *object = [[self.titlearray objectForKey:@"Title"] objectAtIndex:[sortedKeys indexOfObject:string]];

    NSArray *latlong = [[self.locationarray objectAtIndex:[[self.titlearray objectForKey:@"Title"] indexOfObject:object]] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    CLLocation *firstLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[latlong objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue] longitude:[[latlong objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]];
    CLLocation *secondLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation];
    float value = distance / 1000;
    NSString *distancevalue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value];

    if(self.distances.count < [sortedKeys indexOfObject:object])
    [self.distances addObject:distancevalue];

    else if([sortedKeys indexOfObject:object] < self.distances.count && [self.distances objectAtIndex:[sortedKeys indexOfObject:object]])
    [self.distances replaceObjectAtIndex:[sortedKeys indexOfObject:object] withObject:distancevalue];

}
```

The first `NSLog` displays '36' as it should do, but when the `for` statement is called, no log appears for "Adding object number 36". It only goes up to 35. It's very strange and I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array** has starting index from **0 to n records**.

So it display **record count perfectly** but **when iterated it starts from 0** to n record.

U have 36 record but when iterated it starts from 0 to 35 .

Answer (score 1):

Since in array, object index count **starts from 0** and your last object index is **35** for which total will be **36** objects.

For instance, if an array consists of **X objects**, its index **starts from 0 and ends at X-1**

Comment: Strange that you and @Prince have such similar answers.

Comment: may be because its the most convenient answer... you can check of the oldest answer

Comment: I wonder how many times you and @Prince have upvoted each other?

Comment: If you have a doubt then its useless... cause we dont know each other in person

Comment: But you both work at the same company (which would have been easy to see until you removed that from your profile).

Comment: why dont u ask @Prince about working in the same company? Its useless, atleast for me, to carry on this discussion

Comment: @Neo, but there are 36 objects in the first array so I am trying to put 36 objects in the second array. What is going wrong, because it should be counting them properly?

Comment: counting starts from 0 so your first object will be counted with index  zero and your second object will be  counted with index 1, third object with index 2 and so on until your 36th object with index 35... so if you count the total number of index 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11.....35 then you will have 36 indexes which is equal to the number of objects